# How to search using keyword analyzer on Elastic Search?

Tags: elasticsearch, tire

I have problems setting up Elastic Search with Tire and keyword type analyzer.

My mapping definition is this:

```
Tire.index 'my_index' do
    delete

    create :mappings => {

        "my_type" => {
          :properties => {
            :id => { :type => 'string', :index => 'not_analyzed', :include_in_all => false },
            :user_id => { :type => 'string', :index => 'not_analyzed'},
            :team_id => { :type => 'string', :index => 'not_analyzed', :analyzer => 'keyword'},
            "_timestamp" => { :enabled => true,  :path => "created_on"}
          }
        }
}
end
```

I add some data with 
`team:id: "blah-blih-bloh"`

If I search

`curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/my_index/my_type/_search?q=team_id:blah'`

I can found the data I inserted, also if the analyzer was "keyword".

I would like to user facets to group data for team_id, but given that it seems that the keyword analyzer is not working as expected, I cannot retrieve good results because it tokenizes the "team_id" field.
If I have two users with team_id = "blah-blih-bloh", I would get 2 results for "blah", 2 for "blih", 2 for "bloh" and 2 for "blah-blih-bloh".

Do I miss something?

EDIT: I solved the problem, it was Tyre-related. Tyre was not correctly destroyng and recreating the index, if I did

```
curl -XDELETE
```

on the index of ElasticSearch, and then I executed the same code as before, mappings were created correctly, data were inserted fine and everything worked as expected.

Comment: I have the EXACT same problem. No answer unfortunately =(

Comment: Can you do a GET mapping on that index, and tell me if it says keyword analyzer?

Comment: I solved this problem, sorry for not editing the question. The problem was Tyre not correcly recreating the index, it seemed that the instructions were not enough, and it did not detroy the index. Removing with a curl -XDELETE did the trick.